# Powering on an external test system with UNIX/Python commands

Tags: python, unix, shutdown, reboot

I'm trying to write up a power cycling Python script to test an external system. One part of the script is that the off-time between the iterations of power off and power on must be variable, and so I'm looking for any UNIX and/or Python command or set of commands that can trigger the boot-up of a system.

I've considered simply using the `-shutdown.exe -r -t 00` UNIX command but that doesn't allow for a time delay between off and on.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such thing out of the box (for non-advanced-server  HW). To switch on the machine you must probably write into the BIOS settings. The BIOS may have a power-on date/time. Maybe you can alter BIOS settings, read here: https://serverfault.com/questions/498557/is-it-possible-to-change-bios-settings-from-linux

Anyway, if power cycle isn't really needed, you can put the machine in a diferent run level: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/run-levels-intro.html

Comment: unfortunately, a power cycle is needed... a full power down and boot is required to accurately complete the test

Answer (score 0):

The solution may depend on the OS and BIOS of the external system. For example, under Ubuntu this 
sets the machine to wake up in 5 minutes and then 
shuts down the machine:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"
sudo sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 5 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"  
sudo shutdown -h now
```

I learned [this here](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup).

If the above commands work on your system, then you can incorporate them into a Python script, using [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) to call the commands.

Comment: The OS i'm using is either Windows 7 or 8.1. How would I go about doing this in the command prompt?

Comment: [Here](http://www.kozeniauskas.com/itblog/2008/01/18/remotely-change-bios-settings/) they talk about set bios settings from Windows.